# How to prepend text in a specific note in Notes iOS on iphone using shortcuts-app

Tags: iphone, ios, shortcuts-app

I am using iOS 15.7.6 on iPhone 7 Plus and I'm using shortcuts to add the current date to a note. The only way I can do this is by "appending" the date to the note. That means that I have to scroll a very long list to see the last input. How can I "prepend" the date to that list?

I tried storing the current body of the note in a variable, then removing the body of the note itself, fetching the current date, appending the fetched current date to the note body, then appending the previously stored body back to the note. But apparently there is no such thing as "remove" the body of the note, nor is there a "Prepend to Note" function.

Comment: Each note already shows the last edit date in the list...

Comment: The note "contains" the dates when my app was tapped. So each time I tap the app, it adds the date to the "body" of the note, a specific note.